# MongoDB $in query multiple predicates

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a table as follows:

```sql
------------------------------------------------------
|   row_num | person_id   | org_id   | other columns |
|-----------|-------------|----------|---------------|
|         0 | person_0    | org_0    |       .       |       
|         1 | person_1    | org_0    |       .       |
|         2 | person_2    | org_0    |       .       |
|         3 | person_3    | org_0    |       .       |
------------------------------------------------------      
|         3 | person_0    | org_1    |       .       |
|         4 | person_1    | org_1    |       .       |
|         5 | person_2    | org_1    |       .       |
|         6 | person_3    | org_1    |       .       |
------------------------------------------------------
|         6 | person_0    | org_2    |       .       |
|         7 | person_1    | org_2    |       .       |
|         8 | person_2    | org_2    |       .       |
|         9 | person_3    | org_2    |       .       |
------------------------------------------------------
```

The primary key is `(person_id, org_id)`. This combination is guaranteed to be unique.

Let us say, I have lists `person_ids` and corresponding `org_ids` for certain persons and I want to fetch their records from the collection.

```py
persons = [("person_0", "org_0"), ("person_1", "org_1"), ("person_3", "org_1")]
person_ids, org_ids = zip(*persons)
```

In this case the expected output is columns from rows `0, 4, 6`.

I can always find the answer by finding the intersection of the following two queries, but I was wondering if there is any smarter way to do this:

`db.collection.find({person_id: {$in: person_ids})`

`db.collection.find({org_id: {$in: org_ids})`

Comment: Can we have some sample dataset, sample input, and the corresponding expected output, please? Or is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xf_R-eT9W_T) what you are looking for?

Comment: but you need the recprds merged?
for example: `[{person_id: 1}], [{org_id: 10}, ...]` or `{persons: [{person_id: 1}, {person_id: 2},], org: [{org_id: 10} , {org_id: 20} ....]}`

Comment: @ray: I have added sample data.

Comment: @Midoelhawy: Yes, output needs to be merged. The records belonging to `person_id` and corresponding `org_id` should be returned.

I am not looking for a cartesian product of two queries if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in one query this way

```
db.collection.find({
  person_id: { $in: person_ids },
  org_id: { $in: org_ids }
})
```

Here's simple demo: https://mongoplayground.net/p/TwYxZRDFVBI

Comment: I have added some sample data.

Comment: Thanks, then this query is exactly what you're looking for. I've created a playground to demostrate this query https://mongoplayground.net/p/TwYxZRDFVBI

Answer (score 0):

If you need it by `OR` operator you can do it by this command :

```
db.collection.find({
    $or:[
        {person_id: { $in: person_ids } },
        {org_id: { $in: org_ids  } }
    ]
})
```

If you need it by `AND` operator you can do it by this command :

```
db.collection.find({
    person_id: { $in: person_ids },
    org_id: { $in: org_ids  } 
})
```